# Setting float variable to Array value

Tags: c#, arrays

I have objects that instantiate at every random Array value and i want to do something if a specific Array value is selected.

I can't find a way to use Array in an if statement to check if a certain Array was selected, so is there a way to set my float variable to an Array value?

```
public float[] spawnTime;
public float spawnValue;

IEnumerator Spawner()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnTime[Random.Range(0, 5)]);
    
    Instantiate(object, 1f, 1f), Quaternion.identity);
    

    spawnValue = ***// the random selected spawnTime.***

    if (spawnValue == ***// the random selected spawnTime.***)
    {
       Debug.Log ("Do something");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I've received a solution to this from another site if anyone was interested.

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnTime.Length);
 
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnTime[randomIndex]);
 
 if(spawnValue == spawnTime[randomIndex]){
  // Do something
 }
 
 or
 
 float randomFloat = spawnTime[Random.Range(0, spawnTime.Length)];
 
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(randomFloat);
 
 if(spawnValue == randomFloat){
 // Do something
 }
```